# odoo, add many2many in invoice using _prepare_invoice

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to add a many2many fields in my invoice but when i use _prepare_invoice method i got an empty fields and no records in x_fleet_vehicle_invoice_rel table! so hope someone can help me with this...

```
class SaleOrderInherited(models.Model): 
    _inherit = 'sale.order' 

    order_field = fields.Many2many('fleet.vehicle', 'x_fleet_vehicle_sale_order_rel', 'order_id', 'vehicle_id', string='Order Field ') 

    @api.multi 
    def _prepare_invoice(self): 
        res = super(SaleOrder, self)._prepare_invoice() 
        res['invoice_field'] = self.order_field 
        return res 


class AccountInvoiceInherited(models.Model): 
    _inherit = 'account.invoice' 

    invoice_field = fields.Many2many('fleet.vehicle', 'x_fleet_vehicle_invoice_rel', 'invoice_id', 'vehicle_id', string='Invoice Field')
```

Comment: Rename class SaleOrderInherited to class SaleOrder and class AccountInvoice

Comment: Accessing a relational field (Many2one, One2many, Many2many) always returns a recordset, empty if the field is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `res['invoice_field'] = [(6, 0, self.order_field.ids)]`

More here: http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/x2many.html